# snowflake Bind variable

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can i insert current_date() bind variable into a table  using snowflake stored procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE abc (
"P_MESSAGE_ID"            FLOAT,
"P_THEATER"               STRING,
"P_MONTH"                 STRING,
"P_MESSAGE"               STRING,
"P_START_DATE"            STRING,
"P_END_DATE"              STRING,
"P_ACTION"                STRING,
"P_MSG_TYPE"              STRING,
"P_LOGGED_USER"           STRING
)
RETURNS variant
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

var  query="INSERT INTO abc(MESSAGE_ID,MESSAGE,THEATER,CREATED_BY,CREATE_DATE,UPDATED_BY, UPDATE_DATE,MONTH,START_DATE,END_DATE,MESSAGE_TYPE)
VALUES(E2E_BANNER_MSG_S.NEXTVAL,
:2,
:3,
:4,
:5,
:6,
:7,
:8,
:9,
:10,
:11);"
var sql = snowflake.createStatement
({
sqltext: query,
binds :[P_MESSAGE_ID,
P_MESSAGE,
P_THEATER,
P_LOGGED_USER,
current_date(),
P_LOGGED_USER,
current_date(),
P_MONTH,
P_START_DATE,
P_END_DATE,
P_MSG_TYPE]});

var result = sql.execute();
$$;

Iam getting the below error :

execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: CURRENT_DATE is not defined in ABC at '                                        P_LOGGED_USER,' position 40

Can you help me to resolve this issue

Thanks,
nikhil

Answer (score 0):

You can not add functions as bind variables but why do you need to add them? You can directly put them into your SQL:

```
create table abc(MESSAGE_ID number ,MESSAGE varchar,THEATER varchar ,CREATED_BY varchar,CREATE_DATE varchar,UPDATED_BY varchar, UPDATE_DATE varchar,MONTH
                 varchar,START_DATE varchar,END_DATE varchar,MESSAGE_TYPE varchar);
                                                 
                                                 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc ( P_THEATER STRING, P_MONTH STRING, P_MESSAGE STRING, P_START_DATE STRING, P_END_DATE STRING, P_MSG_TYPE STRING, P_LOGGED_USER STRING )
RETURNS variant LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
AS $$
var P_MESSAGE = P_MESSAGE;
var query= "INSERT INTO ABC (MESSAGE_ID,MESSAGE,THEATER,CREATED_BY,CREATE_DATE,UPDATED_BY, UPDATE_DATE,MONTH,START_DATE,END_DATE,MESSAGE_TYPE) VALUES (E2E_BANNER_MSG_S.NEXTVAL,:1,:2,:3,current_date,:3,current_date,:4,:5,:6, :7)"; 
var sql = snowflake.createStatement ({ sqlText: query, binds :[P_MESSAGE, P_THEATER, P_LOGGED_USER, P_MONTH, P_START_DATE, P_END_DATE, P_MSG_TYPE ]});
var result = sql.execute(); 
$$;
                                                 
CALL abc( 'Arena', 'Jan', 'Test message', '2021-01-01' , '2021-01-10', 'Open', 'Jack' );

select * from abc;
```

Comment: i just tried replicating it, when i use change it using the sql statemnt then we are getting the below error.

Comment: 100183 (P0000): Execution error in store procedure ABC:
empty argument passed
At Snowflake.createStatement, line 15 position 21

Comment: can you use "?" marks instead of numbers, maybe you are missing some arguments

Comment: sure , let me verify using that one , few of the people suggested to use numbers instead of ?, which one would be the right approach

Comment: you use E2E_BANNER_MSG_S.NEXTVAL for message_id, so no need to send P_MESSAGE_ID. check the bind variables, the arguments, and make sure none of them are empty.

Comment: i have create a sequence for the messgae id  so  used the next val

Comment: I have removed unused columns, and use :1 notation as you need to use the same parameter for twice (p_logged_user). Also fixed some syntax errors like sqltext. please check my response again.